# I can't save the excel range as a pdf with two column references

Tags: excel, vba

i cant save excel range as pdf when the conditional i want naming the pdf use 2 column in the pdf

```
Sub ExportAndEmailPDFName()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pdfFileName As String
    Dim Name As String
    Dim mnth As String
    

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Salary")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:L40")
    

    Name = ws.Range("D4").Value 
    mnth= ws.Range("K3").Value
    emailName = Name & " " & mnth
    pdfFileName = "D:\PDF Salary\" & emailName & ".pdf" 
    
    ' Export the range to PDF (error in here)
    rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
        

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

but working when use this code

```
Sub ExportRangeToPDFWithEmailName()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pdfFileName As String
    Dim emailName As String
    

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Salary")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1:L40")
    emailName = ws.Range("O4").Value
    pdfFileName = "D:\PDF Salary\" & emailName & ".pdf" ' Replace with your desired folder path
    

    rng.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=pdfFileName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
    

    Set ws = Nothing
    Set rng = Nothing
End Sub
```

VBA,Script save excel range as pdf with 2 name reference in column sheet

Comment: What does `can't save` mean? Is there any run-time error? What's the content of cell D4 and K3? The code works well if there isn't any invalid char as file name.

Comment: cant save to pdf (range A1:L40), yess run time error 1004, D4 content is Name and K3 is month (July - not number 08), i want save range A1:L40 as pdf, but save the pdf name reference D4 & K3, like Agnes July.pdf

Comment: If `D:\PDF Salary` is NOT exist, it raises 1004. If it is not the case, you could input any text into D4 and K3, then test the code again.

Comment: omg K3 content is not text its date number 30/08/2023,

but when im add this  

 Dim dateValue As Date
    dateValue = ws.Range("K3").Value
    Dim formattedDate As String
    formattedDate = Format(dateValue, "dd/mm/yyyy")

its show same massage error run time, and D:\PDF Salary is exsist

Comment: Is _pdfFileName_ a valid filename? (e.g. / is not a valid character)

Comment: its done, im change K3 date as text and save smoothly, because windowns system wont save "/"